# Microsoft Azure Speech Translation not working [JavaScript SDK]

Tags: azure, translation, speech-to-text

This example is not working anymore:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/node/translation.js

And the demonstration in azure website is not working too:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-translation/#features

Anyone is having problem too?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Troubleshoot the Speech SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speech SDK 1.21 was release and fixed this bug.

See release notes: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/releasenotes?tabs=speech-sdk#speech-sdk-1210-april-2022-release

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for letting us know, this should be fixed now.